# AFNetworking 2.0: Process data before it is cached

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, caching, afnetworking

Is there a way to change some data — more specifically: Images — before it is cached?

I download images from an api that are unreasonably big. I'd like to scale them down as soon as they arrive, so that they need less space and I don't have to scale them each time they are loaded from cache.

I can do the scaling either in an subclass of `AFImageResponseSerializer` or in a subclass of `STAHTTPRequestOperation`. But in either case the images are already cached in the original size.

How can I access and alter the data before it is written to cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I achieved it by overwriting `connection:willCacheResponse:` in my operation class.

```
@implementation MYImageRequestOperation

-(CGSize)size
{
    return CGSizeZero; // overwritten in subclasses
}



-(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:cachedResponse.data];
    GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter *resizingFilter = [[GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter alloc] init];

    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGSize size = [self size];
    [resizingFilter forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio: CGSizeMake(size.width * scale, size.height * scale)];
    GPUImagePicture *gpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [gpuImage addTarget:resizingFilter];
    [gpuImage processImage];

    UIImage *smallImage = [resizingFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

    NSData *data;

    if([[cachedResponse.response.MIMEType lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"image/png"])
    {
        data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);
    } else {
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallImage, .9);
    }

    NSCachedURLResponse *response = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:cachedResponse.response data:data];
    return response;
}
@end
```